# Is it possible to pass a non-final variable to a method of an anonymous class?

Tags: java

I need to send code to another method, as the number of methods in the class may change, I use reflection. But the problem is that I can not enumerate them in a loop `benchmarkMethods.get(i).invoke(set, null);`, because it is possible to me anonymous class can only pass final variable. What do I do in this case?

```
public void RunAllBenchmarks(final Object set, boolean randomOrder) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    final List<Method> benchmarkMethods = new ArrayList<Method >();
    final Class benchClass = set.getClass();
    Method[] methods = benchClass.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++){
        Annotation[] annotations = methods[i].getAnnotations();
        if (annotations.length != 0){
            for (int j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++)
            if (annotations[j].annotationType().toString().contentEquals("interface Benchmark"))
                benchmarkMethods.add(methods[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkMethods.size(); i++){
        String name = null;
        Method method = benchmarkMethods.listIterator().next();
        MeasureAndRecord(name, new IFunc() {
            @Override
            public Object onEvent() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {

                return benchmarkMethods.get(i).invoke(set, null);
            }
        });

    }

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    PrintResults(writer);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are having a problem with your solution of the actual problem that you are working on. Could you try describing the problem that you are trying to solve by applying reflection, not the problem with applying reflection?

Comment: I'm writing a benchmark, it was possible to do without reflection, but using it I can add new methods in a separate class.

Comment: I just started learning Java recently, I would like to know whether you can come up with something here. For example. Net, which uses a delegate can be passed, and a local variable

Comment: Is your problem that you cannot call `benchmarkMethods.get(i)` in your `onEvent()` method?

Comment: `var item = order[i];`
    `string name = item.Key.Name ?? item.Value.Name;`
    `MeasureAndRecord(name, () =>` `item.Value.Invoke(set, null));`

Comment: Yes, I can not change the variable **i**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be to avoid the anonymous inner class. i.e. have a class `MethodIFunc implements IFunc` that invokes the method on its `onEvent()` i.e.

```
for (...) {
    Method method = ...

    // this class calls method.invoke(..) inside its onEvent() method
    MethodIFunc mi = new MethodIFunc(method, set);
    MeasureAndRecord(name, mi);
}
```

Another approach (btw: you have a double iteration in the second `for-loop` I assume this is not the actual code) could be to use the `for-each` statement that allows the variable to be declared final:

```
for (final Method method : benchmarkMethods) {
    ...
    MeasureAndRecord(name, new IFunc() {
        @Override
        public Object onEvent() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
            return method.invoke(set, (Object[]) null);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add, there is a trick I use to pass non-final variables into an anonymous class. Taking a section of the code you wrote above, I've made some small changes to show how I do it.

I've assumed here `measureAndRecord` is a method (I've decapitalised the first character to signify that) and that `IFunc` is the class that you are creating an anonymous extension of. I've also assumed that `Method method ...` is supposed to be the method you want to pass to your anonymous class (because in your code it doesn't do anything).

The trick here is to add a new method called `init` which you can pass your variables to (final or non-final) and which returns `this` (which in this case is the anonymous class). What happens is the anonymous class is called, the `init` method is immediately called, and then the object (which is an IFunc as required) is returned and used.

You **must** call the `init` method upon construction (before assignment) and you **cannot** chain methods together in this way. The reason is once the object is returned from the first method call, it is an IFunc, **not** the anonymous subclass that you created, and so Java will no longer recognise anything but the overriden methods after that.

Anyway, have a play. I find it **very** handy, if a bit of a cheat. Even when Java 8 comes along and allows virtually final variables to be passed, this will still work with the variable variables.

```
...

for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkMethods.size(); i++) {
    String name = null;
    Method method = benchmarkMethods.get(i); // Assumption on my part

    measureAndRecord(name, new IFunc() {
        // Anonymous class variables matching what we want to pass
        Method method;
        int i;

        // Cheating "Constructor"
        public IFunc init (Method method, int i) {
            this.method = method;
            this.i = i;
            return this; // Must return this for assignment
        }

        @Override
        public Object onEvent() throws InvocationTargetException,    
            IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
                return method.invoke(set, null);
            }
        }.init(method, i)); // Note that init is called BEFORE assignment
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mutable int wrapper, e.g.

```
final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkMethods.size(); i++){
    String name = null;
    Method method = benchmarkMethods.listIterator().next();
    ai.set(i);
    MeasureAndRecord(name, new IFunc() {
        @Override
        public Object onEvent() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
            return benchmarkMethods.get(ai.get()).invoke(set, null);
        }
    });
}
```